# Compiling with Make command in any IDE

Tags: c, xcode, eclipse, makefile

I spent ages searching and couldn't find anything that helped.

I'm doing a project in college where I have to create a virtual disk and file system using C. Most of the code was given already and we need to compile using a Makefile. Using the standard "Build" command fails to compile the software. I've never used Makefiles before and I don't really know how they work but there were some basic instructions given on how to compile with it. I tested it out in Terminal and if I go to the file location and type `make` it compiles fine and I can run the binary executable file that is created. The problem is that doing this is not only tedious but it doesn't let me use the debugger built in to Xcode.

Is there any way that I can set Xcode to run this `make` command instead of just building the way it does now? I also installed Eclipse and can code passably well in that if anyone can tell me how to do something similar there.

EDIT: I'm pretty much willing to use any software at this point. I have spent days trying to find a way compile inside an IDE with a Makefile. I also have Visual Studio on a Windows computer and have been trying to figure out how to compile with that, also to no avail. If anyone could please help me I would be so grateful.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I suspect your best bet is to create a Command Line Tool project in Xcode and import all the existing files into that.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is what I was doing. After starting a new project I set it up as OSX > Application > Command Line Tool.

It seems however that the command line is just for the output, I can't find any way to use it for any usual command-line operations.